# После закрытия программы остаётся процесс в диспетчере задач

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, отладка, visual-studio-2017

После закрытия программы остаётся процесс в диспетчере задач.

Как определить из-за чего это происходит?

При запуске программы через F5 программа после закрытия правильно завершается.

Но после закрития при запуске Alt F5 висит в диспетчере.

Comment: _Как определить из-за чего это происходит?_ - с теми данными, что вы нам дали - никак.

Comment: программа большая. куда смотреть? есть какая-то инструкция что проверять?

Comment: В дебаг режиме все гуд?

Comment: Программа занимает один поток ?Может у вас `Thread` неправильно работает.

Comment: AGS17 при закрытии окна процесс висит и дебаг не отключается автоматически. Но если остановить дебаг на кнопку остановки то процесс исчезнет

Comment: Кроме потоков - вероятно, проблема в том, что вы не закрываете главное окно. Например, так: открылось главное окно - потом нужно открыть другое - делаете Hide главного и Show нового - потом новое закрыли, а старое осталось. Hide != Close.

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543704/wpf-application-still-runs-in-background-after-closing

Answer (score 1):

CLR завершает .NET-приложение тогда, когда все его не [фоновые](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground(v=vs.110).aspx) потоки завершили работу. Поток завершает работу, когда его главная функция возвращает управление (или при вызове метода Abort). Для приложений WPF поведение основного потока определяется свойством [Application.ShutdownMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), по умолчанию он завершается при закрытии всех окон.

Соответственно, методика отладки такой ситуации такова:

- Убедиться, что в программе не остается невидимых окон, мешающих закрытию основного потока.
- Если приложение создает (явно) дополнительные потоки, которые бесконечно работают и никогда не возвращают управление, при их запуске нужно установить свойство `IsBackground = true`.
- Если приложение не создает дополнительных не фоновых потоков, после завершения всех своих потоков нужно приостановить выполнение программы (<kbd>Отладка</kbd> - <kbd>Приостановить все</kbd>) и открыть окно потоков (<kbd>Отладка</kbd> - <kbd>Окна</kbd> - <kbd>Потоки</kbd>). В данном окне можно увидеть содержимое стека для каждого потока, и на основе этого понять источник проблемы. Если проблемный поток создает код сторонней библиотеки, нужно обратиться к ее документации и выяснить, как это исправить.
- Если проблемным потоком оказался "GC Finalizer Thread", нужно убедиться, что для всех IDisposable-объектов вызывается метод `Dispose` или его аналог (для файловых потоков, соединений с БД и т.п. нужно **всегда** явно освобождать ресурсы, чтобы избежать проблем с буферизацией/кэшированием).

Дело в том, что финализаторы - очень ненадежный метод освобождения ресурсов. В некоторых ситуациях они могут приводить к взаимоблокировке, если поток сборщика мусора пытается взять Lock или на объект, занятый другим потоком, выполнение которого было прервано сборкой мусора (см. например [здесь](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/sasha/2010/06/30/sta-objects-and-the-finalizer-thread-tale-of-a-deadlock/) описание такой ситуации для STA COM-объектов).

Вызов метода `Environment.Exit` позволяет принудительно завершить программу (независимо от числа активных потоков), но так делать не следует. При этом не вызываются блоки finally в выполняющемся коде, как следствие - какие-то данные могут не дойти из промежуточных буферов до их места назначения (файл, БД, ...)

**Примечание** - потоки из ThreadPool по умолчанию являются фоновыми, о них можно не заботиться, они никогда не предотвращают  завершение программы.

*Руководство на основе обсуждения в недавнем вопросе "Консольное приложение не завершается", который почему-то снесли, поэтому оставляю информацию здесь.*