# с# Как принудительно завершить поток при закрытии приложения?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Создаю tcp-чат. На клиентской стороне есть метод для получения сообщений, который запускается в отдельном потоке. Метод никогда не завершает свое выполнение и, следовательно, при закрытии приложения процесс не убивается. Подскажите пожалуйтса как поправить?

```
public void ReceiveMessage()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] data = new byte[64]; // буфер для получаемых данных
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                int bytes = 0;
                do
                {
                    bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                    builder.Append(Encoding.Unicode.GetString(data, 0, bytes));
                }
                while (stream.DataAvailable);

                string message = builder.ToString();
            }
            catch
            {
                //ошибка
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Надо в обработчике события на закрытие приложения добавить проверку, есть ли незавершенные потоки, ну и позокрывать их. Что-то типа `_thread.Abort();`

Comment: Связанный: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/668502/После-закрытия-программы-остаётся-процесс-в-диспетчере-задач

Comment: `Thread.Abort` весьма [опасен](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2011/01/threadabort.html). Каждое его упоминание должно сопровождаться объяснением этого (ссылкой на любой хороший ресурс).

Comment: Во-первых используйте Task вместо Thread, во-вторых создайте CancellationTokenSource и в цикле проверяйте `while(!MyCancellationTokenSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested) { ... some code }` создайте метод `Cancel` или `Stop` и в нем сделайте `MyCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/573579/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто установите вашему треду свойство `IsBackground = true` это заставит его умереть при завершении процесса. Подрбнее [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground(v=vs.110).aspx)

Но это топорное решение, которое годится только для простейших случаев. Если в вашем потоке появится некая сложная логика, то следует предусмотреть механизм нормального завершения потоков. То есть, при выходе из приложения, надо как-нибудь уведомить об этом код внутри потоков чтобы он корректно завершил свою работу (вышел из цикла `while` в вашем случае) и освободил все ресурсы.

Простейший пример:

Замените ваш `while (true)` на `while (!appQuit)`, а когда пользователь закрывает приложение, присваивайте переменной `appQuit` значение `true`. В этом случае переменная `appQuit` обязательно должна быть объявлена с ключевым словом `volatile` (иначе, выход может не состояться). Пример ошибки из-за отсутствия `volatile` описан [тут (в голубой рамке "Do We Really Need Locks and Barriers?")](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx)

Ну и в камментах в принципе верно подсказывают, что нет смысла изобретать велосипед когда можно сделать через [`CancellationToken`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Зачем что то изобретать, есть же CancellationToken для таких дел

Comment: @tym32167 да, можно через CancellationToken тоже.

Comment: Если советуете использовать для выхода из цикла в другом потоке переменную, то **обязательно** указывайте, что она должна быть помечена [volatile](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile). Иначе это будет грубейший баг.  И да, как уже сказали, лучше использовать CancellationToken: [Отмена в управляемых потоках](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/threading/cancellation-in-managed-threads).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а зачем? Что будет, если не пометить?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov о, большое спасибо за замечание! До вашего комментария я был уверен, что в таком простом сценарии это не требуется т.к. значение меняется только из одного потока и это атомарная операция. Благодаря вашему комменту я нагуглил пример того, что может пойти не так (процессор может держать переменную в регистре). Благодарю. Сейчас попробую улучшить ответ :)

Comment: @Monk - _Модель памяти C# в теории и на практике_: [1 часть](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/jj863136), [2 часть](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/magazine/jj883956.aspx).